# How to add a numbered box into a frame?

Tags: pdftex, enumerate, framed

I have a number of frameboxes in different sections. I need to give numbers to those frameboxes as given in the example image. There should not be a vertical gap in between those two boxes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{microtype,xparse,tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment }{}{}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment }{empty,
  left = 1em, top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,
  borderline west = {2pt} {0pt} {black!20},
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {response} { +m O{black!20} } {
  \IfValueT {#1} {
    \begin{reviewer-comment~}
      \setlength\parindent{2em}
      \noindent
      \ttfamily #1
    \end{reviewer-comment~}
  }
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces
} { \bigskip\par }

\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer { m } {
  \section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}

\title{Response of comments }
\author{Rudresh \and Somnath }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
{\color{blue} the goal of this article}
\end{framed}

Text description for frame 1.

\begin{framed}
{\color{blue} the goal of this article}
\end{framed}
Text description for frame 2.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  In this case, the solution may be dependent on exactly how you are building your framebox.

Comment: Why the same question again ? You asked the question yesterday, changed it with each comment you wrote and left my answer basically useless there

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need it as it is in figure attached without autocounter as i have many subsections

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: The term `autocounter` is misleading. You want to reset it with each section and numbered, but you don't you  want it with `autocounter`. Actually you **do** want an auto counter, because it should be reset with each section.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that issue is solved. The only issue is vertcal gap between two boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is far from perfect and not using `tcolorbox`. I don't get what you mean with no autocounter. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcounter{myframC}[section]
\newcommand{\myframe}[2][0.5]{%
    \par\noindent% you might remove this line!
    \refstepcounter{myframC}%
    \begingroup%
    \fboxsep=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\fbox{\makebox[1em][c]{\themyframC}}}%
    \endgroup%
    \fbox{\parbox[t]{#1\textwidth}{\hspace{1.1em} #2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\myframe{I have a framebox. In the framebox, I want to give a number at the
    leftmost top corner. How do I get it using \texttt{\string\newtcolorbox}
    without autocounter.%
}

\end{document}
```

It allows an optional argument to `\myframe` to change the width, e.g. `\myframe[0.7]{...}` uses `0.7\textwidth` as the width for the box. The default is `0.5\textwidth`.

[image: results]

Comment: I have different sections. So, i need to start again from 1. How to do that.

Comment: That's what I meant when I wrote I do not understand what you mean. I thought, maybe you don't want it to be reset or something like that. Do you also want the numbering something like: "1.4" with the "1" the section number and the "4" the box number?

Comment: Actually I have different sections and in each section I need to start from 1. I do not need something like 1.4.                                        One more issue I am getting a vertical gap in between two boxes.i.e before

Comment: See my edit. You might remove the line containing `\par\noindent` for the vertical placement.

Comment: not working with:             \NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer { m } {
  \section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}

Comment: Then add a `\setcounter{myframC}{0}` to your command. The `\section*` command doesn't increment the section-counter and therefore doesn't reset `myframC`.

Comment: yes...I got it. but what about the box seperation?

Comment: Could you please update your question with an image illustrating your separation problem?

Comment: uploaded the image. You can clearly see above the 2.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi this doesn't happen on my pc. Did you alter anything from my code? Which pdf-viewer do you use? Some may be unprecise (try xpdf if you're running Linux). The only big issue I get is when the content of the framed box is only one line, else it works fine for me.

Comment: I am using texstudio on windows 7

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi [here](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) is a Windows version of XPF available. You might try watching the results with it. I don't have much time right now. Maybe I can get back to it later this evening.